# next/prev month is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, request, php-carbon

So I have this view that shows a table and two buttons (next/prev). Each button has a query string `/?date=next` that I capture in my controller using `request()->has('date')`.

```
<a class="button is-primary is-outlined" href="/?date=prev">Previous</a>
<a class="button is-primary is-outlined" href="/?date=next">Next</a>
```

The user shall be able to go to next month, and the month after that depending on how many times he clicks on the next/prev button.

Initially, I had two approaches. First, I thought to myself that I can use a `$count` that increments whenever the user clicks the button in `$post->whereMonth('date', $this->count)`. Second, simply use the Carbon library, `$post->date->addMonth()`.

In both approaches, the date remain the same despite the number of times the next/prev button was clicked.

First approach:

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    protected $count; 

    public function __constructor(){
        $this->count = 0; 
    }

        public function show(Hour $post){
            if(request()->has('date') == 'next'){
                $posts = $post->whereMonth('date', $this->count);
                $this->count++; 
            } else if(request()->has('date') == 'prev'){
                $posts = $post->whereMonth('date', $this->count);
                $this->count++; 
            }

            return view('user.table', compact('posts')); 
        }
}
```

Second approach (favorite):

```
public function show(Hour $post){
    if(request()->has('date') == 'next'){
        $posts = $post->date->addMonth(); 
    } else if(request()->has('date') == 'prev'){
        $posts = $post->date->subMonth(); 
    }

    return view('user.table', compact('posts')); 
}
```

I've seen that Laravel provide the query builder `increment`, but that only work for columns, and not variables.

Is there a way I can make this work by remembering the previous date as shown in the second approach.

Comment: So you are filtering the data, you want it only show the data based on requested month, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just want to display a date. In this case, do this:

```
public function show(Hour $post)
{
    $months = request('months', 0);

    if (request('date') === 'next'){
        $posts = $post->date->addMonth();
        $months++;
    } elseif(request('date') === 'prev'){
        $posts = $post->date->subMonth();
        $months--; 
    }


    return view('user.table', compact('posts', 'months')); 
}
```

And in the view:

```
<a class="button is-primary is-outlined" href="/?date=next&months={{ $months }}">Previous</a>
<a class="button is-primary is-outlined" href="/?date=next&months={{ $months }}">Next</a>
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will be testing this as soon as possible!

Comment: This worked with minor adjustments, added the incrementing value as a argument in the query builder like `$posts = $post->whereMonth('date', ++$months)->get();` However, I have one question, why do you have a zero value in `$months = request('months', 0);`. I am not familiar with this approach :)